# How to get array from multi select when submit form [AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I need to get array with ids when multi select box is submitted. The array should, then, look like this:

```
[13,14,15]
```

`13,14,15` are ids inside objects...

here is what my select box looks like:

```
<select ng-model="groups.group" multiple="multiple" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" ng-options="group as group.name for group in groups.groups">
<option value="object:13" label="Group4">Group4</option>
<option value="object:14" label="Group6">Group6</option>
<option value="object:15" label="Group7">Group7</option>
</select>
```

Here is my angular code inside template:

```
<select ng-model="groups.group" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" ng-options="group as group.name for group in groups.groups">
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.groups = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  $scope.selectedGroups = [];
  $scope.addedGroups = [];

  $scope.add = function() {
    $scope.addedGroups = $scope.selectedGroups;
  };
});
```

```css
select,
div {
  width: 300px;
}
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <select multiple="multiple" ng-model="selectedGroups">
    <option ng-repeat="group in groups" value="{{group}}">{{group}}</option>
  </select>
  <button ng-click="add()">add to box</button>
  <div>{{addedGroups}}</div>
  {{selectedGroups}}
</div>
```